# Fancybox JQuery closeClick no found

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using the latest version of jQuery and Fancybox both of the official pages, but for strange reason does not work on popup when inputs inside.

That is not working the blur on inputs, my code is:

```
$("#popup").fancybox({
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers   : { 
        overlay : {
            closeClick: false,
        }
    }
}).trigger("click");
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Link example: http://jsfiddle.net/YkH5G/

Comment: Your question is confusing... what's going on? What do you expect to happen and what doesn't happen? Can you link to an example?

Comment: Ouh, sorry: http://jsfiddle.net/YkH5G/

Comment: What does "you can click to inputs" mean? You can click inside the inputs? Why wouldn't you be able to? What's the behavior supposed to be otherwise?

Comment: The behavior should be able to write in the input but apparently does not work, I can click and fill my entry.

Excuse my English, I speak Spanish

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17897/discussion-between-colleen-and-raul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, fancybox is loading on every click of popup, rather than onload. Because the content of popup is in the fancybox, every time you click in the fancybox you're clicking on popup and therefore loading fancybox again.

What you need to do is create a link with an href of popup and use *that* to trigger fancybox.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YkH5G/2/

Answer (score 1):

Improved solution according to the author of the plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $("#popup"),
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers   : {
            overlay : {
                closeClick: false,
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/YkH5G/1/

By author plugin: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/410